# Face detection code in Open CV

Tags: c, opencv

In my program i am detecting the face of a person, my code is working well, but i am worry about this code, as for eye detection "cascade.detectMultiScale()" have many parameters, while  for Face detection i am using these few parameters, and how it detects the face, whether we have not initialized the size of detecting object in  "cascade.detectMultiScale()"

```
 cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.2, 2);

for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
    Rect r = faces[i];
    rectangle(src, Point(r.x, r.y), Point(r.x + r.width, r.y + r.height), CV_RGB(0,0,255));
}
```

Comment: yes, what is the question?

Comment: @DídacPérez i want to know that how the above code works that it return the face in image, please if you don't mind elaborate on the code, that how its execution flow, and what actually it does internally

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read some manual regarding integrated Open CV functions ([Open CV cascade classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=detectmultiscale#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale)). Last 2 parameters are "minSize" and "maxSize", which can set minimum and maximum size of detected object. For my project I am detecting narrator's face on some 1080p HDTV channel, so my configuration is like this:

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(500, 500) );
```

...which means I have scale factor=1.1 with only 1 possible face detected.
`CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE` means that algorithm is in charge of scaling the image, not the detector (which is, in general, slower). You can also use something like `0|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT` if you want to extract the biggest object among all the candidates. In my case, I also forced detector to search for objects not smaller than 500x500 px, which have also speed up my real-time processing and prevent detector from making false detections.
You also should keep in mind, that integrated detector is derived from some predefined parameters (especially in training phase). If you are really interested in making better detector (and better detection accuracy and/or performance) for your application of use, you should consider custom made classifier. But be aware: although modified parameters (number of training iterations, training mode, object properties, object alignment, etc.) COULD make things better, but good understanding of each one of them (and impact between them and on the final result), as well as fine-tuning is needed in order to make some reasonable improvements.